# Rails 3 - How to install awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to install awesome_nested_set in my Rails 3 app. This is a plugin, versus a gem. I've installed gems but never a plugin.

The awesome_nested_set is here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

But that appears to not be Rails 3 friendly, according to several reported issues.

There is a Rails 3 friendly fork here: https://github.com/FreakyDazio/awesome_nested_set

But I'm not sure how to install this? How do I install this plugin in my Rails 3 app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3, install a plugin via:

```
rails plugin install <path to plugin>
```

So, for this plugin:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/FreakyDazio/awesome_nested_set.git
```

Using just `rails plugin` will give you additional information.

Comment: Thanks but that errors. "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `acts_as_nested_set' for #<Class:0x10337e840> (NameError)
"

Comment: Also, it says you can do, Category.rebuild! , where do you run that? in terminal, or using rake Category.rebuild!, both don't work?

Comment: Oh, you're referring to the comment on the other question! I think `rebuild!` is only useful if you're coming from a system where you only have a `parent_id`, and no `lft` or `rgt` fields. Since you were already using a nested set system, you shouldn't have to use it. But, yes, I'd use it on a `rails console` and use `ModelName.rebuild!` if I was in that situation.

Comment: ok thanks, strange that's not working. Given that's a different issue I iopened a new question. I'll accept this answer. Thanks Brandon!

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3, the `script/foo` scripts have been replaced by calling `rails` directly, so in your case, to install the FreakyDazio fork of `awesome_nested_set`:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/FreakyDazio/awesome_nested_set.git
```

Rails by default looks in `vendor/plugins` (which is where `rails plugin install` will install to) for plugins to load (at which time, the plugin's init.rb file will be run). [Here](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/01/rails-3-plugins---part-1---the-big-picture/) is an article about plugins in Rails 3. You might want to read about the [Rails initialization process](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html) as well.

Comment: As I mentioned, the plugin generally lives in `vendor/plugins/<name of plugin>`. Unlike a gem, a plugin is just unpackaged ruby code, so you can certainly edit it if necessary.